# How to return data in a chart?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to return data I am putting inside a `data` const the following way:

```
const data =
            this.state.grades.map((grade) => {
                const object = {}
                score = null;
                if (90 <= grade.value) {
                    score = "A";
                    object.name = "A",
                        object.population = grade.value,
                        object.color = "#27ae60",
                        object.legendFontColor = "#7F7F7F",
                        object.legendFontSize = 15
                } else if (80 <= grade.value && grade.value < 90) {
                    score = "B";
                    object.name = "B",
                        object.population = grade.value,
                        object.color = "#2ecc71",
                        object.legendFontColor = "#7F7F7F",
                        object.legendFontSize = 15
                } else if (70 <= grade.value && grade.value < 80) {
                    score = "C";
                    object.name = "C",
                        object.population = grade.value,
                        object.color = "#feca57",
                        object.legendFontColor = "#7F7F7F",
                        object.legendFontSize = 15
                } else if (60 <= grade.value && grade.value < 70) {
                    score = "D";
                    object.name = "D",
                        object.population = grade.value,
                        object.color = "#f39c12",
                        object.legendFontColor = "#7F7F7F",
                        object.legendFontSize = 15
                } else if (50 <= grade.value && grade.value < 60) {
                    score = "E";
                    object.name = "E",
                        object.population = grade.value,
                        object.color = "#e74c3c",
                        object.legendFontColor = "#7F7F7F",
                        object.legendFontSize = 15
                } else if (50 <= grade.value && grade.value < 60) {
                    score = "F";
                    object.name = "F",
                        object.population = grade.value,
                        object.color = "#c0392b",
                        object.legendFontColor = "#c0392b",
                        object.legendFontSize = 15
                }
                return object;
            });
```

Thing is that, I am not sure why, but when I `console.log(data)`, I get 5 empty "[]" which 5 is correct, since my API returns 5 objects, but after "processing" the data, for some reason it does not return anything.

Now, I want to also input the data into the pie-chart, but again, still nothing.

Here is how I am looking forward to input the data

```
                           <PieChart
                                data={data} // Here 
                                width={350}
                                height={220}
                                chartConfig={{
                                    backgroundColor: "#19B5FE",
                                    backgroundGradientFrom: "#647bff",
                                    backgroundGradientTo: "#9b59b6",
                                    decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
                                    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
                                    style: {
                                        borderRadius: 16,
                                        alignSelf: 'center'
                                    },
                                }}
                                accessor="population"
                                backgroundColor="transparent"
                                paddingLeft="15"
                                style={
                                    {
                                        alignSelf: 'center',
                                        paddingLeft: 20
                                    }
                                }
                            />
```

The way the data should look after being processed is the following way:

```
{
   name: "F",
   population: 1,
   color: "#c0392b",
   legendFontColor: "#7F7F7F",
   legendFontSize: 15
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with my own constant `grades` that looks like that:

```
const grades = [{ value: 100 }, { value: 50 }, { value: 20 }, { value: 90 }, { value: 30 }];
```

and your code returned me this:

```
[{
    name: 'A',
    population: 100,
    color: '#27ae60',
    legendFontColor: '#7F7F7F',
    legendFontSize: 15
  },
...
]
```

So, the map is working on an array of objects with the key `value` in it. You need to check what is your `this.state.grades` looks like and is the objects in array `grades` has the value in it.

The `grade.value` does not match any `if` rule and returns an empty object for each grade.